# Regular expression for int and double

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to find the regular expression for getting the Error value from the following string:

```
{'Sample': '#it{House}', 'Yield': 0.0012267869301467726, 'Error': 0}
```

I tried `"'Error': (\d+.\d+)"` but I have the case that the Error can be either an integer (like 0) or a double value like 0.992. I checked many cases but still cannot find the regular expression.

Comment: Why would you use regex for this?

Comment: Because I read these values from a yaml file.

Comment: If it is yaml, then use the yaml module so that you get the variables as is.  That looks like json though, so maybe the json module would be better

Comment: JSON is YAML, though the standard library has the `json` module but no module for YAML.

Comment: But Yaml isn't json.  That string isn't json because json only uses double quotes .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If that data is indeed formatted with yaml, you can read it with the yaml module (which is *not* part of the default distribution of python):

```
$ python -c 'import yaml,sys; print(yaml.load(sys.stdin.read())["Yield"])' <<<"{'Sample': '#it{House}', 'Yield': 0.0012267869301467726, 'Error': 0}"
0.00122678693015
```